# How to display HTML Image tag in BrowserField in RIM Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, browserfield

I want to display HTML  tag in RIM BB component BrowserField.

```
String str ="<html><body><p><img alt=\"bun\" src=\"http://adodis.in/ram/services/images/stories/food/bun.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"112\" /></p></body></html>";

BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
browserField.displayContent(str, "http://localhost");
add(browserField);
```

How to display above tag in BrowserField? Using Blackberry OS 5.0

Thanks very much in advance..

Comment: are you just trying to figure out how to display a string of HTML content in a BrowserField, or are you already doing that, and the image above is not displaying correctly?

Comment: I can display other content like <p> <br> tags. But cannot display image.

Comment: can you show the java code that you use to display this in your `BrowserField`?  normally, the `<img>` tag should display just fine.  also, which version of BlackBerry OS are you using?

Comment: String str ="<html><body><p><img alt=\"bun\" src=\"http://adodis.in/ram/services/images/stories/food/bun.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"112\" /></p></body></html>";
browserField.displayContent(str, "http://localhost");
I am using Blackberry OS 5.0

Comment: can you **edit** your question above, and post the code into there?  then, you can use the **{ }** button to format it as *code*.  that works better than trying to do it in a comment.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your app, and you see the label `"bun"` displayed (the `alt` text), then I think the problem is just that you don't have network connectivity.  Check your network, especially if you're using the simulator (you can just run the Browser app and try a known URL).

If you are seeing **nothing** where the image should be, then I think the problem is just that you call `displayContent()` **before** you `add()` the `BrowserField` to its parent manager.

So, just change the order of your calls, to call `displayContent()` last:

```java
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
add(browserField); 

String str ="<html><body><p><img alt=\"bun\" src=\"http://adodis.in/ram/services/images/stories/food/bun.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"112\" /></p></body></html>";
browserField.displayContent(str, "http://localhost");
```

Also, you don't really need to specify the `img` `width` and `height` properties in your HTML snippet, as that's the size of the actual image file.  But, that doesn't actually cause a problem ... it's just *extra* HTML code.